# Unreadable data received from bluetooth device

Tags: android, character-encoding, bluetooth, arrays, android-bluetooth

I am trying to receive data from the finger oximeter over bluetooth. Connection works and i receive data in byte[] format, then i convert byte array to string format using UTF-8 encoding and result im getting is in this format:

> > Ba�JBa�OBa�TBa�W
> >     Ba�Z
> >     Ba�\
> >     Ba�]
> >     Ba�]Ba�]Ba�]
> >     Ba�\
> >     Ba�[
> >     Ba�Z
> >     Ba�X
> >     Ba�W
> >     Ba�VBa�UBa�TBa�SBa�RBa�QBa�QBa�PBa�PBa�PBa�OBa�OBa�O@a�O@a�O@a�O@a�N@a�N@a�N@a�M@aa�B

And here is my code:

```
 if(b == delimiter)
 {
   byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
   System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
   final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
   readBufferPosition = 0;

  handler.post(new Runnable()
  {
      public void run()
      {
         Log.v("Test",data);
      }
  });
 }
```

What should i do to receive a readable data for displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this constructor of String class:

```
String dataReceived = new String(mbyteArr, "US-ASCII");
```

You should, however be sure of the encoding name. My examples used "US-ASCII" and "UTF-8", the two most common encoding standards. May be you need to check the standard with the gadget's documentation.